# Center image on border of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve this design:
[image]
The Black Circle is an image (ignore the rectangel). I don't now how to get this working, e. g. centering the circel on the border. Maybe some of you guys can do this?
I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ydygqmz/1/) so you can play around with it.

HTML for StackOverflow:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="manager-textbox">
      <img src="http://www.altpress.com/images/uploads/news/Hello_Kitty.jpg" class="manager-portrait" style="height:100px">
      <div class="manager-text">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean auctor malesuada mauris, sit amet tempus erat dictum eget.
          In eleifend arcu augue. Quisque enim est, eleifend vitae est nec, gravida congue ligula. Proin id convallis
          turpis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div>
```

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760364/image-position-divided-in-half/43760589#43760589

Comment: Updated your [*JSFiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/0ydygqmz/6)

Comment: See also this: https://jsfiddle.net/0ydygqmz/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/0ydygqmz/15/)**

**CSS**

```
// managers
.manager-headline {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: $xcellent-blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.manager-textbox {
    background-color: #f4f6f9;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #303f9f;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.manager-text {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#manager  .teaser-header-what {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.manager-portrait {
 position: absolute;
 top: -50px;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: solid 2px red;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.first{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("http://stuffpoint.com/sea-and-beach/image/27652-sea-and-beach-summer.jpg");
  background-repaet: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.second{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}

.imageContainer{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  top: -30px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("http://i2.cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/130203065116-beyonce-12-super-169.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first">
    
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this one, it is similar:
[Image position divided in half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760364/image-position-divided-in-half/43760589#43760589)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS transform like this..

```
.manager-portrait {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxwm2aq4/

Answer (score 1):

Just change you `.manager-portrait` class to this:

```
.manager-portrait {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid;
}
```